# Get metadata from Winston logger object

Tags: winston

If I create a child logger, like this:

```
const childLogger = winston.child({ requestId: '451' });
```

How can I later retrieve that information from the childLogger object?
Specifically, where in the childLogger object is the requestId field stored?
For example, "childLogger.someField.requestId" or something.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly a response to your answer, but it is how we implemented the correlation ID using `asyncLocalStorage`.

```js
const asyncLocalStorage = new AsyncLocalStorage();

const tracerFormat = winston.format.printf((info:any) => {
    const metadata = asyncLocalStorage.getStore() || {};
    const logContent = {
        ...info, // Content from the log
        ...metadata, // Any additional tag for the logs.
    };
    return JSON.stringify(logContent);
});

const winstonConfig = {
    level: 'debug',
    format: tracerFormat,
    defaultMeta: { service: "MyService" },
    transports: [
        new winston.transports.Console()
    ]
};
const logger = winston.createLogger(winstonConfig);

export function getRequestId(): string {
    const storedData = asyncLocalStorage.getStore();
    return storedData && storedData.get("requestId"); 
}

export function setRequestId(requestId) {
  asyncLocalStorage.enterWith({requestId});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source code [here](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/blob/82608667aa807f25af615a8ff2aa3e303eeb9981/lib/winston/logger.js#L40) the variable appears to be trapped by a closure and not exposed. I switched to [pino](https://github.com/pinojs/pino) which has a method to get the data attached to the logger and has a similar API except for the message and the data are flipped, e.g.

winston

```
log.info("message", {key: "value"})
```

pino

```
log.info({key: "value"}, "message")
```